# Any way around "instance member can't be accessed in an initialized"?

Tags: dart

I would like a member of a class to received a listner from its owner class. So, something like this:

```
class Member {
  Member({required this.listener});
  final VoidCallback listener;
}

class Owner {
  final member = Member(listener: saySomething); // <- error here

  void saySomething() {
    debugPrint('hello');
  }
}
```

But I get the error on `listener: saySomething` that reads `instance member can't be accessed in an initializer`. My understanding is that it's because the compiler builds the Member instance first and then the Owner instance, so doesn't have the locations in memory yet.

I know I can do this in two steps. E.g., instantiate `member` and then assign its `listener` in my constructor or wherever, but it would be really nice if I could assign `listener` when `member` is instantiated.

I'm pretty sure that's not possible but am hoping to be proven wrong?

Comment: Ah. The "already answered" link discusses using the late keyword to lazy initialize. I didn't know you can do that in a single line of code. That's pretty sweet. So, I can `late final member = Member(listener: saySomething);`

Answer (score 0):

You can either pass the function directly into the constructor, or you can make `saySomething` into a static method, rather than an instance method:

```
// Directly passing the function
class Owner {
  final member = Member(listener: () {
    debugPrint('hello');
  });
}

// Using a static method
class Owner {
  final member = Member(listener: saySomething);

  static void saySomething() {
    debugPrint('hello');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. My example was too simplistic. My actual listener can't be static. It references other Owner members. For that reason, I don't think the first option will work either because the other members would need to be in the closure.

Comment: I read the "already answered" like above and it describes how I can late initialize. So, `late final member = Member(listener: saySomething);` which is pretty sweet.